# Is it correct to set localstate from redux store in useEffect

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks

I have a function component whose controls depend(need to be initially set) on a variable from redux store, but the user can modify those variables and later needs to be saved to redux store.  So in the below, key variable may not be set if the Store object has still not initialized.

My question is,

1. Is it correct to keep 'duplicate' source of truth? (ie local state copied from redux store)?
2. Is it correct to call setState from useEffect?

My code is:

```
const myStoreObj = useSelector(state=>state.Store);
const key = myStoreObj?.key;

const [myVar, setMyVar] = useState('');

useEffect({
  if(key){
    setMyVar(myStoreObj.myVar);
   }
},[key]);
```

Comment: Depends why you would do such a thing, if you edit data and want to keep original data in redux state but the user edited data in local state then you're fine to do that.

Comment: I do eventually want to save the user edited data (new value of myVar) back into myStoreObj redux store

Comment: When the user edits data then you don't really have a copy of the original data. You have the initially copied data that the user is changing (and can cancel) and the original data that will become the user edit version if the user chooses to save. Technically you don't have duplicate data because both versions can be different depending on what the user is changing. There may be a reason to store the edited data in redux instead of local state when the edit component can be unmounted or other component need that data.

Comment: I dispatch to redux on a button click.  Till then, i thought keeping state locally makes sense.  When component initially mounts, myStoreObj is empty, hence I initialize myVar to empty string.  Then when myStoreObj does set, I want to update myVar from myStoreObj.  User can subsequently make changes to myVar.  Thanks for your help @HMR